# Find if list in data.table contains word in other column

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data.table. One of the columns is a list of words. I want to see if any of those words appear in another column, which is a single word, for each row. I feel like this should be easy but I am not getting the result I expect.

The difficulty seems to be the fact that the column includes lists, and possibly also that it is inconsistent (i.e. not lists all of the same length, some NAs, some that are just single words)?

**Example data**

```
words_data <- data.table(
  word = c("Lots", "of", "words", "some", "are", "names", 
           "like", "Tom", "and", "Connolly", "or", "Pete", "Dawson"),
  names = c(list(c("Tom", "Connolly")),
            list(c("Tom", "Connolly")),
            list(c("Tom", "Connolly")),
            NA,
            NA,
            NA,
            list(c("Tom", "Connolly")),
            list(c("Tom", "Connolly", "Pete", "Dawson")),
            list(c("Jenny", "Rogers")),
            NA,
            list(c("Pete", "Dawson")),
            "Dawson",
            NA)
)
```

**Desired output**

A data.table filtered to rows where the value in the `word` column can be found in `names` column.

Therefore the only one that would match in this particular dataset would be the 8th row, which has `"Tom"` as the word and `c("Tom", "Connolly", "Pete", "Dawson")` as the names.

**Using %in%**

This just returns one line, but I don't know why this line.

```
> words_data[word %in% names]
     word names
1: Dawson    NA
```

**Using unlist()**

This does identify that words that are names, so basically suggests that the entire names column is unlisted and all of the words checked against, which seems closer but I only want it to check for the row.

```
> words_data[word %in% unlist(names)]
       word                    names
1:      Tom Tom,Connolly,Pete,Dawson
2: Connolly                       NA
3:     Pete                   Dawson
4:   Dawson                       NA
```

**Using sapply**

I thought using `sapply()` might help with the row-wise issue but the output is the same as just doing `word %in% names`.

```
> words_data[word %in% sapply(names, unlist)]
     word names
1: Dawson    NA
```

Comment: A naive solution might be `words_data[mapply(\`%in%\`, word, names)]` but that is probably painfully slow. *edit* - maybe not too bad - couple of seconds per million rows.

Comment: A `tidyverse` one which is logically similar to @thelatemail would be `words_data %>%  filter(map2_lgl(word, names, `%in%`))` (contains backquotes).

Comment: @thelatemail Ooh interesting! For my 2m row dataset, it takes about 3.2 seconds, which I think I can live with. If you post as an answer, I'll accept (though also interested if there are other solutions). Do you happen to know why my attempts produced the results they did?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is essentially just a hidden loop, but it will work:

```
words_data[mapply(`%in%`, word, names)]
#   word                    names
#1:  Tom Tom,Connolly,Pete,Dawson
```

I thought it might scale terribly, but it is *okay*:

```
words_data <- words_data[rep(1:13,1e5),]
nrow(words_data)
#[1] 1300000
system.time(words_data[mapply(`%in%`, word, names)])
#   user  system elapsed 
#  1.329   0.016   1.345
```

The issue with most of the attempts in the question is that they are not considering the `word` and `names` piece-by-piece in vectorised comparison across multiple vectors. `Map` or `mapply` will take care of this:

```
mapply(paste, 1:3, letters[1:3])
#[1] "1 a" "2 b" "3 c"
```

The reasons why the other results didn't work are varied. E.g.:

### %in%

This compares each value of `word` in turn to see if it exists in `names` exactly

```
words_data$word %in% words_data$names
#[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
#[8] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

`"Dawson"` in row 13 of `word` matches `"Dawson"` in row 12 of `names`. It won't match anything else that is a `list` containing `"Dawson"` along with other values though:

```
"Dawson" %in% list(list("Dawson","Tom"))
#[1] FALSE
```

### unlist

"*...basically suggests that the entire `names` column is unlisted and all of the <strike>names</strike> `word` checked against*"

Yep, that's it.

### sapply + unlist

The `sapply` here didn't do anything to the `names` object, because the `unlist` is only run inside every list item anyway:

```
identical(words_data$names, sapply(words_data$names, unlist))
#[1] TRUE
```

Then you can reference the `%in%` logic above for a reason as to why it didn't work as intended.

Comment: Thanks! With my data of 1,747,850 rows and 6 columns I get an elapsed time of 3.168.

Comment: @Megan - have added some comments as to why the other methods didn't work.